# Insert Unique Primary Key into Database using Entity-Framework LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I want to enter unique index value into my database when insert other table data. In this case my table index column `ID` is **unique** but not auto-increment.

I also want to check the maximum of index value in target table. If the table is empty then index value starts from 0, OR if it contains 1 row then the index value starts from 2.

Already I can successfully do this operation using a stored procedure. But I want to do this operation using Entity Framework when saving data.

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreatePerson]
   @Name Nvarchar(50),
   @Code Nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @Id int
   SET @Id = ISNULL(((SELECT MAX([id]) FROM dbo.tbl_Person)+1),'1')

   Insert Into dbo.tbl_Person([Id], [Name], [Code])
   Values (@id, @Name, @Code)
END
```

Can anyone tell me what the LINQ Command for this index value save process?

Comment: You should really better create an auto-increment Id column...

Comment: Change `id` to `GUID` or auto-increment it.

Comment: If I create a Auto-Increment 'Id' Column and delete a column data from database table then what will happend ??
If this serial no = 2, then new column Id start from 3 after 1... not 2 
Understand ? This is a problem for my solution @Sharped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straight translation of your SQL stored procedure into Linq would basically be something like this:

```
var newId = ctx.Persons.Any() ? ctx.Persons.Select(p => p.Id).Max() + 1 : 1;
var newPerson = new Person { Id = newId, Name = someName, Code = someCode };
ctx.Persons.Add(newPerson);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Note: this solution is certainly NOT recommended for inserting unique id's in a database, consider carefully the suggestions of Sharped and Magnus in the comments below the question to better use auto-increment or random guids to solve your problem.

With an auto-incremented id column your code would look like this:

```
var newPerson = new Person { Name = someName, Code = someCode };
ctx.Persons.Add(newPerson);
ctx.SaveChanges();
var newId = newPerson.Id;
```

Note that EF will update the id column of the newly created entity for you in code automagically.